# Converting $\psi(x,y,z)$ to $f(r)Y_l^m$ and calculating expectation value of the angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

I've been trying to solve a particular class of problems, where I'm given a wavefunction $\psi (x,y,z)$ and I'm asked to find the expectation value or eigenvalue related to the angular momentum operators $L^2,L_z,L_+$, etc. My intuition is that I need to break the wave function into a radial part and spherical harmonics.

For example, consider the following wavefunction :

$$\psi = (x+y+3z)f(r)$$

We need to find $\langle L^2\rangle $ for the above wavefunction.
Converting into spherical coordinates, and ignoring the radial part, I get:

$$\psi(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta \cos\phi +\sin\theta \sin\phi+ 3\cos\theta$$

From this, I obtain:
$$\psi(\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{2} \sin\theta e^{i\phi}+\frac{1}{2} \sin\theta e^{-i\phi}+\frac{1}{2i} \sin\theta e^{i\phi}-\frac{1}{2i} \sin\theta e^{-i\phi}+3\cos\theta$$

I can identify the spherical harmonics but they are not normalized. Hence I'm writing the above as:

$$\psi(\theta,\phi) = aY_1^1 + bY_1^{-1}+cY_1^1+dY_1^{-1}+eY_1^0$$
Here $a,b,c,d,e$ are constants.

My question is how can I figure out $\langle L^2\rangle $  from the above? \since I don't know the values of the constants, I'm not able to find out the expectation value.

However, intuitively, I noticed that all the terms have the same value for the angular quantum number $l$, and so in each of the terms, $L^2$ should have an expected value of $l(l+1)\hbar^2 = 2\hbar^2$, so overall the expectation value should come out to be $2\hbar^2$.

However, what about the cases, where all the terms in the superposition do not have the same value of $l$? Is there any way to solve the problem in that case, without memorizing the normalization constants for each of the spherical harmonics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My intuition is that I need to break the wave function into a radial part and spherical harmonics.

Correct.

> I can Identify the spherical harmonics but they are not normalized.

You know the spherical harmonics including their normalization factors.
See for example at [Table of spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#%E2%84%93_=_1):

$$\begin{align}
Y^{-1}_1(\theta,\phi)
 &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta
 &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}\frac{x-iy}{r} \\
Y^{0}_1(\theta,\phi)
 &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}\cos\theta
 &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}\frac{z}{r} \\
Y^{+1}_1(\theta,\phi)
 &=&-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}e^{i\phi}\sin\theta
 &=&-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}\frac{x+iy}{r}
\end{align}$$

You can resolve these to $x,y,z$:
$$\begin{align}
x&=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}r\left(Y^{+1}_1(\theta,\phi)+Y^{-1}_1(\theta,\phi)\right) \\
y&=i\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}r\left(Y^{+1}_1(\theta,\phi)-Y^{-1}_1(\theta,\phi)\right) \\
z&=2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}r\ Y^{0}_1(\theta,\phi)
\end{align}$$

> since I don't know the values of the constants, I'm not able to find out the expectation value.

Using these expressions for $x,y,z$ you can rewrite your
example wave function
$$\psi(x,y,z)=(x+y+3z)f(r)$$
from cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$
to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ with spherical harmonics and constants in front of them.
$$\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=rf(r)\left(
  \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}(1+i)Y^{+1}_1(\theta,\phi)
 +6\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y^{0}_1(\theta,\phi)
 +\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}(1-i)Y^{-1}_1(\theta,\phi)
  \right)$$

With the expression above for $\psi$ you are ready for calculating
expectation values of angular momentum related operators, for example
$\langle\psi|L^2|\psi\rangle$.
Make use of
$$L^2Y^m_\ell(\theta,\phi)=\hbar^2\ell(\ell+1)Y^m_\ell(\theta,\phi)$$
and the [orthonormality of the $Y^m_\ell$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Orthogonality_and_normalization),
so that you actually don't need to do the $\theta,\phi$ integrations
by hand.
You will end up with something like
$$\langle\psi|L^2|\psi\rangle=\text{(some constant)}\int_0^\infty r^3|f(r)|^2dr$$

> Is there any way to solve the problem in that case, without memorizing
> the normalization constants for each of the spherical harmonics?

Don't try to memorize the normalization constants.
It is ok to use a table of spherical harmonics.
Physicists do this all the time.